# number of digits in integer number using prolog

Tags: prolog

can someone help me with this problem ?

[image: SWISH image of code]

```
numofdig(A,B):-
   A>0,
   A is (A//10),
   succ(0,S),
   numofdig(A),
   B is S,
   write(B).
```

this is my code and its not working .

Comment: Welcome! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question?

Comment: Hint: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=number_chars/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
number_of_digits( M , N ) :-
  integer(M),              % is it an integer?
  V is abs(M),             % sign is irrelevant as to number of digits
  number_of_digits(V,1,N). % invoke the helper predicate with the accumulator seeded with 1 (all numbers have at least one digit).

number_of_digits( M , T , N ) :-
    M > 9,                        % Is the value > 9?
    !,                            %   If so, eliminate the choice point (it's not going to stop being 10+ on backtracking)
    T1 is T+1 ,                   %   Increment the accumulator
    M1 is M // 10 ,               %   drop the rightmost digit via integer division by 10
    number_of_digits(M1,T1,N)     %   and recurse down on what's left.
    .                             % Otherwise (the value is 0-9)
number_of_digits( _ , N , N ) .   %   The accumulator has the result.
```

Comment: I would be grateful if you could explain to me the idea of this code , because it is a homework  and the doctor will check my understanding of it.

Comment: @Nn.2 — added annotations.

Answer (score 0):

SWISH (the website in your image) already has `?-` to the left of the query box, you don't need to type it in. Typing it in your query is what causes the error `procedure (?-A) does not exist`.

`succ(0, S)` will always be `S=1`, and `B is S` means B is always 1, that's not right.

`numofdig(A)` can't be right because numofdig takes two parameters.

1. Convert to string and measure the string. That's a cheat for Python, but Prolog doesn't even need that it can tell you directly:

```
?- atom_length(100, Len).
Len = 3
```

2. Ugh this recursive loop version, which you are supposed to struggle through so you can learn about recursion:

For a basic version:

```
% a single digit is length 1
num_dig(N, 1) :-
    N >= 0,
    N =< 9.

% other numbers, divide by 10 to shrink it 1 shorter, 
% get the length of that (recursion down to single digit),
% add 1 to each shorter length on the way back up.
num_dig(N, C) :-
    N > 9,
    A is N // 10,
    num_dig(A, B),
    succ(B, C).
```

Improve it by:

- giving the variables clear names
- making it tail recursive so it can run more efficiently
- making it deterministic so it leaves no choicepoints

3. Scrap all that and calculate the number of digits from the base 10 log of the number:

```
num_dig(N, Len) :-
    Len is ceil(log10(N + 1)).
```

Comment: `atom_length(-3,N)` fails due to the sign being included in the length.

Comment: You explained it very well, I can't thank you enough!